# SSDT 2013 is free for use in Company or need license?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

in our company we still have SQL Server 2008 R2.
We use BIDS.

Can we use SSDT 2013? Is it a free tool? Or it needs a license?

Could not find this info on Microsoft site.

If it´s free, I need something to show Directors Board that we are not having problem using it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First there is a difference between SSDT and SSDT-BI. SSDT is the database projects which lets you manage t-sql. SSDT-BI is for ssis, ssas, ssrs projects.

SSDT and SSDT-BI have merged to become one in the Visual Studio 2015 version but unless you are on sql 2012+ you will need to install the version of SSDT-BI that you need for your sql. If you are on sql 2008 r2 then that is actually SSDT-BI predecessor "BIDS".

If you are using SSDT-BI (or BIDS) just run the installer that comes with the version of SQL you are targetting and install from there, these are free and you pay a license to use the server (unless it is express ahhhhh).

If you are looking at SSDT database projects, then it is a little bit complicated in that SSDT itself is free but it is hosted inside visual studio so your options are:

**Free as in no license cost**

- [SSDT in Visual Studio Shell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

If you do not have visual studio installed when you download SSDT it will install the visual studio shell which is a limited version of visual studio.

- SSDT (DB tools) in Visual Studio Express

If you download and install Visual Studio Express you will get a copy of SSDT database tools (no BI). Downloading a later copy of SSDT will install it into Visual Studio Express.

Express and shell are limited in that you cannot add add-ins (vspackages) to them but they functionally work.

**Not Free as in require a license**

- SSDT in Visual Studio Pro / Ent

If you already have visual studio professional or enterprise installed you will need a license for that. They ship with a version of SSDT and downloading the latest SSDT will install into it.

**Free as in doesn't require a license but does have restrictions**

- SSDT in Visual Studio Community Edition

Visual Studio community edition is the same as professional but it is for community projects or small companies (current requirements, no idea if these ever change):

For organizations

> An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual
>   Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning
>   environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source
>   projects.
>
> For all other usage scenarios:  In non-enterprise organizations, up to
>   five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise
>   organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars
>   in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source,
>   academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios
>   described above.

(Taken from "Visual Studio Community Edition" https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx)

Ed

Comment: Hey Ed, I just edited this to clarify a few things on BI vs DB. Good answer overall and thanks for covering this well!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is free. All versions of SSDT are free as I can remember.

Please read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Quoted: 
"
SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) is a modern development tool that you can download for free to build SQL Server relational databases, Azure SQL databases, Integration Services packages, Analysis Services data models, and Reporting Services reports. With SSDT, you can design and deploy any SQL Server content type with the same ease as you would develop an application in Visual Studio.

This release supports SQL Server 2016 through SQL Server 2005, and provides the design environment for adding features that are new in SQL Server 2016.

SSDT is based on Visual Studio and co-released with SQL Server as a free web download. 
"

Comment: Hi @Jian Huang, Is SSDT2017 free from license cost? It is not mentioned as free in Microsoft site - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Aftab I saw this lines in your link, "The installer lists available Visual Studio instances to add the SSDT tools to. If Visual Studio is not installed, selecting Install a new SQL Server Data Tools instance installs SSDT with a minimal version of Visual Studio, but for the best experience we recommend using SSDT with the latest version of Visual Studio.". So I think it's implicitly free because you can install one without the full version of Visual studio, and the installation will provide you with a minimal version of visual studio.